# Refresh a script every X seconds in LUA

Tags: lua

I want to refresh a script every X seconds to update some kind of lists.
I'll explain myself: I have a roleplay server which has many scripts in lua. There's a single script which gives alerts to players who are police (shoots, fights, etc.) but, everytime, when a new player who's police logs in, he doesn't recieve the alerts, instead of the others.

Could anyone give me some advice?

Thanks

Comment: you say you have a "roleplay server", but you never mention what game this is about :D

Comment: GTA V Roleplay :D